# Responsive css grid not displaying correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, css-grid

I have to build a CSS grid system. Here is some of my initial code:

```
#carousel-data{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3% 40% 54% 3%;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 60% 20%;
    align-content: center;
    height: 72vh;
    margin-top: 8.5vh;
}


.carousel-text-title{ 
    grid-column-start:3;
    grid-row:2/3; 
    justify-self:start;
    font-size:2.5em;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}

.carousel-text-content{ 
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row: 3/4; 
    justify-self: start;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-size:2rem;
    color: white;
}
```

The first part is the container and the other two are some element that are placed in the said container.

This works just fine. But then I found out I had to make the container responsive, that is to modify it's height based on the content displayed. So i went ahead and changed the `height` property to `min-height` thinking this would do the trick. But when I ran the code, everything was messed up. Some rows were missing and elements that had their size specified with % or had set only a max height/width weren't showing.

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Can you help me out please? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here is the HTML fragment(can't put it up on codepen because it's a React App,it would be irrelevant, I can link the github repository if that would be helpful)  :

```
    <div className="carrousel">
                <div className="grid-container">
                    <PageIndicator size={this.props.data.length} activeIndice={this.state.currentIndice} 
                        style={{gridColumnStart:'second',justifySelf:'center',marginTop:'30px'}}
                    />
                </div>
                <div id="carousel-data"  style={this.state.slideBackgroundStyle} className={this.state.style}>
                    <Arrow style={{ gridColumnStart: '1', gridRow: '3', justifySelf: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}
                        orientation='left' onClick={this.changeSlide} />
                    <div className="carousel-image"  style={{gridColumnStart:'2/3',gridRow:'2/4' ,justifySelf:'center'}}>
                        <img src={this.props.data[this.state.currentIndice].picture}
                            style={this.props.data[this.state.currentIndice].style ? 
                                { ...this.props.data[this.state.currentIndice].style, display: "inline-block", maxWidth: '95%', maxHeight: '100%' } : { display: "inline-block", maxWidth: '95%', maxHeight: '100%' }} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-text-title">
                            {this.props.data[this.state.currentIndice].title}
                        </div>
                    <div className="carousel-text-content" >
                            {this.props.data[this.state.currentIndice].text}
                        </div>
                    <Arrow style={{ gridColumnStart: '4', gridRow: '3', justifySelf: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}
                        orientation='right' onClick={this.changeSlide} />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant html to got with your css?  Or even better a working codepen/jsfiddle?  That way we can better diagnose your issue.

Comment: I've added the HTML

Comment: Need a codepen or jsfiddle which replicates your issue.